# Where is the chain of narrators for this narration?

Tags: hadith, history, uloom-al-hadith, ilm-ar-rijal, seerah

**ووقف عمر بن الخطاب- وقد أخرأه الخبر عن وعيه- يقول: إن رجالا من المنافقين يزعمون أن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم توفي، وإن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم ما مات، لكن ذهب إلى ربه كما ذهب موسى بن عمران، فغاب عن قومه أربعين ليلة، ثم رجعت إليهم بعد أن قيل قد مات.**

I took the narration above from the following link:-

https://al-maktaba.org/book/9820/426

**I am not able to find the chain of narrators for this narration. Kindly help me.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your linked book cites **(4) ابن هشام 2/ 655** this means page 655 of the 2<sup>nd</sup> volume of Ibn Hisham, which is likely referring to the well known work of seerah. Volumes and pages vary with the publisher, but in this case maybe the same edition is available online where you can find its chain:

> #### قال ابن إسحاق: قال الزهري، وحدثني سعيد بن المسيب، عن أبي هريرة
>
> <sup>—  [سيرة ابن هشام](https://al-maktaba.org/book/23833/1393)</sup>

Comment: So this is basically the chain of narrators? قال ابن إسحاق: قال الزهري، وحدثني سعيد بن المسيب، عن أبي هريرة